# What are possible reasons that my AppWidgetProvider will receive data from 3rd party app in onReceive?

Tags: java, android

Recently, I am experiencing some weird crash report from Firebase Crashlytics.

```
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: id.dana.model.CurrencyAmountModel
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2305)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2255)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2162)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2495)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getIntArray(BaseBundle.java:1164)
       at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:64)
       at com.yocto.wenote.widget.CalendarAppWidgetProvider.onReceive(CalendarAppWidgetProvider.java:234)
```

I feel weird because my app never have use/ access to class `id.dana.model.CurrencyAmountModel`. I have totally clueless where does the class `id.dana.model.CurrencyAmountModel` come from?

It seems like a 3rd party app is able to "inject" data into my `AppWidgetProvider`?

My `AppWidgetProvider` is defined as follow.

```
<receiver android:name="com.yocto.wenote.widget.CalendarAppWidgetProvider"
    android:label="@string/widget_calendar_name"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/calendar_widget_info" />
</receiver>
        
public class CalendarAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        ...

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why does my `AppWidgetProvider` is receiving an unknown data `id.dana.model.CurrencyAmountModel`, and how I can avoid such?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like a 3rd party app is able to "inject" data into my AppWidgetProvider?

Sure. Your `AppWidgetProvider` is publicly accessible by any other app. Any app can send a broadcast to it that it will pick up.

> Do you have any idea why does my AppWidgetProvider is receiving an unknown data id.dana.model.CurrencyAmountModel

Some app is sending a broadcast with a `CurrencyAmountModel` as an extra. Based on the stack trace and the implementation of `AppWidgetProvider`, my guess is that this invalid value is under the `AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS` key. Hopefully, this is a bug in the other app and not something malicious.

> how I can avoid such?

AFAIK, an `AppWidgetProvider` has to be exported for it to work. You could run an experiment and see if `android:exported="false"` still gives you a working app widget, but it would surprise me.

If that fails, you could wrap the `super.onReceive()` in a `try`/`catch` block to prevent the crash. Given the `AppWidgetProvider` implementation, if your `catch` block is invoked, probably your provider did not get called with any of the standard callbacks (e.g., `onUpdate()`). You could add some logging to try to get a sense of whether affected users get *any* good `super.onReceive()` calls:

- If they do, the probably the app widget is working normally other than these rogue broadcasts, so you could write off the failures as just some annoyance
- If they are always affected, you might need to try calling `onUpdate()` yourself from time to time

Comment: I thought also should not be exported, and I have it that way, but the official example here https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets says android:exported="false", so what is the correct way? Could it be that using android:exported="true" has side effects? Sometimes my widget is not updating, so I am wondering here...